# Execution of code is skipping next lines of code in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have added some code to my flutter app and while testing it I found that a line of code was not being executed. While debugging it I found that after the line where I add a new user to a Cloud Firestore account the next lines are skipped without an error.

The code for adding the new user works fine but there is not an error.

Here is the code:

```
  Future<User> handleSignUp(email, password) async {
    UserCredential result = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password); <<< This finishes fine but exits the function
    final User user = result.user!; <<< This line is skipped
    newUser.userId = user.uid; <<< This line is skipped

    return user;
  }
```

After the user is added the execution goes out of the function and goes to the next step and everything works fine except inside the function the line

```
newUser.userId = user.uid;
```

never gets executed and so the userId is never saved and so the association between the login credentials and the user profile never gets made.

Why would the remaining lines in the function get skipped but I don't get an error?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Here is how I call handleSignUp:

```
final newAddedUser = handleSignUp(email, password);
```

Comment: Could you share what createUserWithEmailAndPassword does?

Comment: It creates a password and email based account in Cloud Firestore. I am looking into version 9. I may be using version 8.

Comment: are you awaiting handleSignUp when you call it? How does that part of your code look like?

Comment: I added the line where I call the function to the original post.

Comment: `handleSignUp` is an asynchronous function.  Execution will reach the call to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and `handleSignUp` will immediately return a `Future` to its caller.  The lines in `handleSignUp` after that call will be executed at some indeterminate point later after the call to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` completes.  If you're certain that those lines will *never* get called, then check to see if you're silently swallowing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
      } catch (error) {
        var e = error as FirebaseAuthException;
        Print(e.message!);
      }
```

And instead of getting the Uid from the function, you can get the current UserID anywhere by using

```
userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
```

it will save the CurrentUser uid in userId.

Comment: for your answer but the process is that the current user is adding a new user. So, I don't need the current uid, I am trying retrieve the new uid.